# C++ Paho MQTT connection as a subscriber issue

Tags: c++, makefile, mqtt, paho

I'm pretty new to C++ and was playing around with the Paho MQTT C++ client.
I've rearranged the sample async subscriber, but ran into an error of 'connection lost, cause: connect onSuccess called'. Spent hours trying to find the solution to no prevail.

[image]

My Main file:

```
int main()
{
    subscriber();
    return 0;
}
```

My header file: 'subscriber.hpp' ..has all the dependacy and mqtt/async_client.h

```
int subscriber();
```

My source file: subscriber.cpp

```
#include "subscriber.hpp"

const std::string SERVER_ADDRESS("tcp://localhost:1883");
const std::string CLIENT_ID("eclipse_subscriber");
const std::string TOPIC("topic2");

const int   QOS = 1;
const int   N_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 5;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Callbacks for the success or failures of requested actions.
// This could be used to initiate further action, but here we just log the
// results to the console.

class action_listener : public virtual mqtt::iaction_listener
{
    std::string name_;

    void on_failure(const mqtt::token& tok) override {
        std::cout << name_ << " failure";
        if (tok.get_message_id() != 0)
            std::cout << " for token: [" << tok.get_message_id() << "]" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void on_success(const mqtt::token& tok) override {
        std::cout << name_ << " success";
        if (tok.get_message_id() != 0)
            std::cout << " for token: [" << tok.get_message_id() << "]" << std::endl;
        auto top = tok.get_topics();
        if (top && !top->empty())
            std::cout << "\ttoken topic: '" << (*top)[0] << "', ..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

public:
    action_listener(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Local callback & listener class for use with the client connection.
 * This is primarily intended to receive messages, but it will also monitor
 * the connection to the broker. If the connection is lost, it will attempt
 * to restore the connection and re-subscribe to the topic.
 */
class callback : public virtual mqtt::callback,
                    public virtual mqtt::iaction_listener

{
    // Counter for the number of connection retries
    int nretry_;
    // The MQTT client
    mqtt::async_client& cli_;
    // Options to use if we need to reconnect
    mqtt::connect_options& connOpts_;
    // An action listener to display the result of actions.
    action_listener subListener_;

    // This deomonstrates manually reconnecting to the broker by calling
    // connect() again. This is a possibility for an application that keeps
    // a copy of it's original connect_options, or if the app wants to
    // reconnect with different options.
    // Another way this can be done manually, if using the same options, is
    // to just call the async_client::reconnect() method.
    void reconnect() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
        try {
            cli_.connect(connOpts_, nullptr, *this);
        }
        catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << exc.what() << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Re-connection failure
    void on_failure(const mqtt::token& tok) override {
        std::cout << "Connection attempt failed" << std::endl;
        if (++nretry_ > N_RETRY_ATTEMPTS)
            exit(1);
        reconnect();
    }

    // (Re)connection success
    // Either this or connected() can be used for callbacks.
    void on_success(const mqtt::token& tok) override {}

    // (Re)connection success
    void connected(const std::string& cause) override {
        std::cout << "\nConnection success" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\nSubscribing to topic '" << TOPIC << "'\n"
            << "\tfor client " << CLIENT_ID
            << " using QoS" << QOS << "\n"
            << "\nPress Q<Enter> to quit\n" << std::endl;

        cli_.subscribe(TOPIC, QOS, nullptr, subListener_);
    }

    // Callback for when the connection is lost.
    // This will initiate the attempt to manually reconnect.
    void connection_lost(const std::string& cause) override {
        std::cout << "\nConnection lost" << std::endl;
        if (!cause.empty())
            std::cout << "\tcause: " << cause << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Reconnecting..." << std::endl;
        nretry_ = 0;
        reconnect();
    }

    // Callback for when a message arrives.
    void message_arrived(mqtt::const_message_ptr msg) override {
        std::cout << "Message arrived" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\ttopic: '" << msg->get_topic() << "'" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tpayload: '" << msg->to_string() << "'\n" << std::endl;
    }

    void delivery_complete(mqtt::delivery_token_ptr token) override {}

public:
    callback(mqtt::async_client& cli, mqtt::connect_options& connOpts)
                : nretry_(0), cli_(cli), connOpts_(connOpts), subListener_("Subscription") {}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int subscriber()
{


    mqtt::connect_options connOpts;
    connOpts.set_keep_alive_interval(20);
    connOpts.set_clean_session(true);

    mqtt::async_client client(SERVER_ADDRESS, CLIENT_ID);

    callback cb(client, connOpts);
    client.set_callback(cb);

    // Start the connection.
    // When completed, the callback will subscribe to topic.

    try {
        std::cout << "Connecting to the MQTT server..." << std::flush;
        client.connect(connOpts, nullptr, cb);
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception&) {
        std::cerr << "\nERROR: Unable to connect to MQTT server: '"
            << SERVER_ADDRESS << "'" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Just block till user tells us to quit.

    while (std::tolower(std::cin.get()) != 'q')
        ;

    // Disconnect

    try {
        std::cout << "\nDisconnecting from the MQTT server..." << std::flush;
        client.disconnect()->wait();
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not apply irrelevant tags to your questions. C and C++ are two distinct languages. Since your post has nothing to do with C, I removed the `C` tag for you.

Comment: Did the original example work? If so, undo each of the changes you made to the code until it starts working again.

Comment: So when I go back to running the subscriber.cpp file as a whole from my makefile, it's all good and works. The parts I've changed is instead of the main 'int main(int argc, char* argv[])' I changed to 'int subscriber()'. I then call that function from my main fuel.

Comment: and thanks for pointing out the wrong tag

Comment: Ya, there can be only one `main` linked into your program. So are you good to go now? Problem solved?

Comment: I have one main function in my main.cpp file. Which calls the function in the subscriber.cpp file 'int subscriber()' . Still getting a connection lost message